# removing body background color of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a an iframe on my page that currentlyhas a background color of grey, I want to change the color to be white but cant seem to do it. I have tried using jquery but not sure if this is correct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
});
```

basically at the moment the bo tag within the iframe has the inline background-color: #f1f0e9

can anyone suggest how I can update this background color? i've tried css also but nothing.

The problem is on this page http://cromorevillage.com/book.html

The iframe is the booking element and the background color of this extends down the page because an iframe height had to be added to allow for all booking options to be shown when selected?

Comment: Does the `src` attribute of the `iframe` have matching domain, protocol and port to its parent page?

Comment: @alex no the iftame is external

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment...

> Does the `src` attribute of the `iframe` have matching domain, protocol and port to its parent page?

Your response...

> No the `iframe` is external.

The reason you can not change it is because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: thanks so nothing can be done to update this background-color?

Comment: @kylle Not unless you can circumvent Same Origin Policy :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').attr('bgcolor', 'white');
});
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to solve the problem, I have added a link to the actual page problem if that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.css('background-color', 'white');
```

`background-color` is the css style you are looking for.

---

You need to add a `P3P` header with the value of `CP="CAO PSA OUR"` to allow cross-domain interfacing.

Comment: I've updated the code from backgroundColor to background-color but nothing has changed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/JPK9F/ shows that it's changing the color correctly.

Comment: Try pointing the `iframe`'s `src` attribute to `http://google.com`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RqnVM/).

Comment: I was just showing that for proof that `background-color` is the correct css style.  I can't add a P3P header to jsFiddle.  =D